# Shiny: how to control width of rownames() in renderTable?

Tags: r, shiny

the code below produces a table of inputs with 3 rows and 3 columns (to simplify the situation - see picture below). Based on the inputs, I need to produce 9 histograms below the table of inputs, and importantly the histograms should be aligned vertically with the input boxes. It's not the case at the moment.

One option I'm considering is to use an offset of 1 before including the plots. To make sure that the plots are aligned, the rownames of the inputs (alt1, alt2, a3) should appear in such a way that they occupy precisely 1 column to match with the offset. By default, renderTable seems to use an automatic adjustment. I've searched online but couldn't find a way to control the width of the rownames.

Can anyone help please ? Any inputs would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

```
library(shiny)
library(grid)
library(gridBase)

u <- shinyUI(navbarPage(
"My Application",
tabPanel("Component 1",
       fluidPage(

         fluidRow(column(6,
          tableOutput('decision_Matrix'),offset=0)       
         ),
         fluidRow(column(5,
           plotOutput('decision_Matrix_plots')
           ,offset=1)       
         )
       )),
tabPanel("Component 2")
))

s <- shinyServer(

function(input,output) {

  output$decision_Matrix <- renderTable({

        matrix_input <- matrix(data = NA,nrow = 3,ncol = 3)
  for (j in 1:3) {
    for (i in 1:3) {
      matrix_input[i,j] <- paste0("<input id='C",j,"_A",i,"' type='number' class='form-control shiny-bound-input'  value='",input[[paste0("C",j,"_A",i)]],"'>")
    }
  }

  rownames(matrix_input) <- c("alt1","alt2","a3")

  colnames(matrix_input) <- c("crit1","crit2","t3")

  matrix_input
},include.rownames = TRUE,sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)

output$decision_Matrix_plots <- renderPlot({    

  layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),nrow = 3,ncol = 3))
  for (j in 1:3) {
    for (i in 1:3) {
      set.seed(123)
      n <- input[[paste0("C",j,"_A",i)]]
      if (is.null(n) || is.na(n) || n < 1) n <- 1
      hist(rnorm(n),breaks = 10,main=sprintf("histogram of rnorm( %d )",n))
    }
  }
  recordPlot()
})

})
shinyApp(ui = u,server = s)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like you said rownames is messing up your alignment. Using fluidRow and column Shiny is making use of Bootstrap. For the underlying principles fluidRow and column have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp

The solution for the vertical alignment is to put your rownames in a separate column. The following changes fix the vertical alignment.

```
    ...
                     fluidRow(column(1,
                                     tableOutput('m_rownames'),offset=0, align="left"),
                             column(5,
                                tableOutput('decision_Matrix'),offset=0, align="right")
                     ),
                     fluidRow(column(5,
                                     plotOutput('decision_Matrix_plots')
                                     ,offset=1, align="right")
                     )
    ....

            },include.rownames = FALSE,sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
            output$m_rownames <- renderTable({ c("alt1","alt2","a3") })
```

This puts your rownames in a separate column with width 1 and your matrix and plots are each put in 5 corresponding columns. However this messes up the horizontal alignment of your rownames and matrix. I might have a little time to look at this later, but for now I'll leave it to you to tweak that.

This is the result
[image]

Comment: Thanks Etienne, I've had the same idea actually, but the heights of the rows in m_rownames is different from the rows' heights in the table because it includes numeric inputs. I've found the following to fix this manually: "tags$head(tags$style(type="text/css", "#m_rownames table td {line-height:245%;}"))". 245% was found by trial and error. However this is not satisfactory. This is a simplified case: in my table, I also have radio buttons which take up more vertical space. I think that the rownames should not be in a different table. Please let me know if you find smth. I work on this too. H

Comment: Horizontal aligning items in different columns is very difficult, because the placement of items within a column is determined by the browser and it is dependent on the size of your browser window (and other things). You can try `fixedPage` to get rid of this dependency. The other option is what you've done. In that case the browser determines the placement of items within the row, so 2 version of same problem. I don't think there is a solution for this, but when there is you might find it at the HTML or CSS forum.

Answer (score 1):

As far as alignment is concerned the best option is to make 3 columns. Each containing 3 inputs and the 3 corresponding outputs. The first column shows the rownames the others don't. This requires some reorganization and it is not perfect since the first column will differ from the others. Here some code

```
    ...
    fluidRow(
           column(4,
                 tableOutput('decision_MatrixC1'),offset=0),
           column(4,
                 tableOutput('decision_MatrixC2'),offset=0),
           column(4,
                 tableOutput('decision_MatrixC3'),offset=0)
    ),
    fluidRow(
           column(3,
                 plotOutput('decision_Matrix_plotsC1')
                                     ,offset=1),
           column(4,
                 plotOutput('decision_Matrix_plotsC2')
                                    ,offset=0),
           column(4,
                 plotOutput('decision_Matrix_plotsC3')
                                   ,offset=0)
     )
     ....
     output$decision_MatrixC1 <- renderTable({                        
             matrix_input <- matrix(data = NA,nrow = 3,ncol = 1)
             for (j in 1:1) {
                    for (i in 1:3) {
                              matrix_input[i,j] <- paste0("<input id='C",j,"_A",i,"' type='number' class='form-control shiny-bound-input'  value='",input[[paste0("C",j,"_A",i)]],"'>")
                     }}                        
             rownames(matrix_input) <- c("alt1","alt2","a3")                        
             colnames(matrix_input) <- c("crit1")

             matrix_input
            },include.rownames = TRUE,sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)

            output$decision_MatrixC2 <- renderTable({
                    matrix_input <- matrix(data = NA,nrow = 3,ncol = 1)
                    for (j in 1:1) {
                            for (i in 1:3) {
                                    matrix_input[i,j] <- paste0("<input id='C",j+1,"_A",i,"' type='number' class='form-control shiny-bound-input'  value='",input[[paste0("C",j+1,"_A",i)]],"'>")
                            }}                        
                    rownames(matrix_input) <- c("alt1","alt2","a3")
                    colnames(matrix_input) <- c("crit2")
                    matrix_input
            },include.rownames = FALSE,sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
```

And almost the same for the 3rd column of plots. Obviously this code needs some cleanup, but I wanted to leave it as close as your code as possible. Instead of organizing it in columns like this you can organize it in rows in a similar fashion. The result is

[image]